# How Can I Evaluate $\int_{0}^{\frac{a}{2}}x^{a-1} (1+x)^{b-1}(1-x)^{c-1} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, logarithms

**Question:-** Evaluate $$\int_{0}^{\frac{a}{2}}x^{a-1} (1+x)^{b-1}(1-x)^{c-1} dx$$

Where $a,b,c \in Z$

In order to find Definite Integrals of type

$$\int \frac{ln(x) ln(1+x) ln(1-x)}{(ax+b)(cx+d)}$$

Let $$I_{a,b,c}=\int_{0}^{\frac{a}{2}}x^{a-1} (1+x)^{b-1}(1-x)^{c-1} dx$$

Differentiate both sides w.r.t $a$

$$I^{'}_{a,b,c}=\int_{0}^{\frac{a}{2}}x^{a-1} (1+x)^{b-1}(1-x)^{c-1}ln(x) dx$$

Now Differentiate w.r.t $b$

$$I^{''}_{a,b,c}=\int_{0}^{\frac{a}{2}}x^{a-1} (1+x)^{b-1}(1-x)^{c-1}ln(x)ln(1+x) dx$$

Again differentiating w.r.t $c$

$$I^{'''}_{a,b,c}=-\int_{0}^{\frac{a}{2}}x^{a-1} (1+x)^{b-1}(1-x)^{c-1}ln(x)ln(1+x)ln(1-x) dx$$

Letting different integral values of $a$, $b$ and $c$.we can evaluate numerous integral of above type. But I find that It is very hard to find $I_{a,b,c}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not surprising that you feel the problem difficult. For
$$J= \int x^{a-1} (1+x)^{b-1}(1-x)^{c-1} dx$$ a CAS gives
$$2a(1+a)x^{-a} J=$$ $$2 (a+1) F_1(a;-c,-b;a+1;x,-x)+$$ $$a x
   (F_1(a+1;1-c,-b;a+2;x,-x)-F_1(a+1;-c,1-b;a+2;x,-x))$$
where appear three Appell hypergeometric functions of two variables.

For the definite integral $I_{abc}$ replace $x$ by $\frac a 2$.

Answer (score 2):

lets look at a similar problem:
$$x^a(1+x)^b(1-x)^c=x^a(1+x)^b(1-x)^{b+c-b}=x^a(1-x^2)^b(1-x)^{c-b}$$
then do the binomial expansion of $(1-x)^{c-b}$ and try the substitution $u=x^2$, This should give you a series of incomplete beta functions

Comment: Can you please explain more about incomplete beta functions point. According to my understanding Incomplete beta function will be form by $t^a (1-t)^b$ But we also have an extra binomial sum that would prevent to form incomplete beta function.

Comment: @user1055 as long as the integral is convergent the summation and integral can be interchanged so you can represent your integral as a series of Beta functions

Comment: This works if $0\leq a\leq 2$.

Answer (score 1):

Just expand $(1+x)^{b-1}$ and $(1-x)^{c-1}$ using the Binomial theorem, and we get that our integral is equal to

$$\sum_{j=0}^{b-1}\sum_{k=0}^{c-1}{b-1\choose j}{c-1 \choose k}\frac{(-1)^k}{a+j+k}\left(\frac{a}{2}\right)^{a+j+k}$$

If you feel like compactifying this representation using properties of binomial cooeficients, then feel free.